# Looking for js library recommendations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a library or framework that would make creating the image below possible in html and javascript. Anybody have any ideas?

[[image]]

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can pretty much do this with jQuery, React, Angular, Vanilla, etc.. I would recommend going with the one you or your team know better. If you face some challanges, we are here to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of jQuery or JavaScript.. just use bootstrap columns .. first column will be col-9.. the next 3 will be col-1
You could also just write your own css html to have column 1 70% wide and rest 10% each.

Even better you could use css grids. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column

Comment: If I am correct, the true difficulty here does not lie in creating the html "boxes" themselves but in coloring them with respect to the model values. The OP can either loop using Razor or using a script. My understanding is that visual effects are usually better done using a script (e.g. jQuery) to manipulate classes.

Comment: Coloring them will be easy by adding css classes. I thought the OPs image was static.. if it's dynamic then yes - That can be done with css grids of course  using addClass in jQuery and it's a very simple code examples available all over the internet.

Comment: When I look at this nice image, I can see someone clicking mindlessly on each box... :-)

Comment: Then onclick addClass will be able to toggle the css class and hence the color .. :)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was able to create the graphic with css grids. The grids need be need to be filled based on a passed in value with the 13 attributes above, containing a value from 1 to 3

Answer (score 0):

A plugin would add complexity and constraints to your project, IMO. Also, finding the plugin to do exactly what you desire may become a larger endeavor.

This visual is commonly done using CSS and using attributes such as `data-status="1"`, `data-status="2"`, `data-status="3"`. Using jQuery, you can add classes to each element based on `data-status`.

If this is a path you want to follow, feel free to start some code and we'll be glad to build upon.